# Not using asp listbox well

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, scriptmanager

All I wish to do is simply click a button and the text in a textbox is automatically added as an item in the listbox. Shouldn't this be straight forward? Whilst debugging, the item is added and I can see the text by watching ListBox1.Items[0], but nothing is displayed in the web page. I had the same problem which i did not solve, in a console application! Can some one please guide me to what I am doing wrong?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(TextBox1.Text));
    }
```

Many thanks

Edit:

In a past project, I used the DataSource property, which worked perfectly. I have never yet managed to use the add Items! May be there is some sort of refresh or update?

**Page code:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="295px"></asp:ListBox>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: its empty!, but this is my aspx page. 

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">  </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="295px">
        </asp:ListBox>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your listbox is  outside of the update panel. Pop it inside the update panel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="AddItem" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks guy! worked like a charm! Now at least I know the code I am writing is good, I must find the same problem that I have with my console application now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You have to move the ListBox into the UpdatePanel, otherwise it will not be updated.

The reason for that is, that ASP.NET is sending the whole HTML of the UpdatePanel back to the client. Since the ListBox is not part of the UpdatePanel, it won't be updated.